# Why does my system need so many different versions of Visual C++?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

Currently, I'm in the process of cleaning about 100GB worth of gunk out of my system (I don't take good care of my PC), and I've noticed that I have 13 different versions of the Visual C++ runtime spanning from 2015 to 2015, both x86 and x64.

[image: This seems unnecessary...]

I've always noticed programs asking me to constantly install a very specific version of Visual C++ and I just went along with it for the most part.

However, is there really a reason to have 13 different versions of what is essentially the same software? Why do programs demand to have a *very specific* version of Visual C++? And, most importantly, which ones are safe for me to delete? Or, if none are safe to delete, can they be consolidated somehow so that they take up less of my disk space?

Comment: Windows is written in C I think.

Comment: For the save disk space part, they are quite small compared to other stuff you might have around the disk to really care about.

Comment: to fix the DLL hell from Win9x where a newer C runtime DLL broke older tools and installing an older DLL broke new tools. Now each tool picks the correct C runtime from WinSxS folder.